# How to invoke this kind of java script on Vb.Net programmatically

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I do know nothing about java. And I have a web page that includes this kind of java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        hX_6.addBehavior("f:button", "onclick", new hX_6.JSFBehaviorGeneric("action:confirm","target:Save or not?"));
        hX_6.onPageLoad();
 </script>
```

I tried to invoke that code like this :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("hX_6.addBehavior(""f:button"", ""onclick", "new hX_6.JSFBehaviorGeneric(""action:confirm"");")
```

But i can't. How can i invoke this code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution would be to add an identical script tag to the webpage's body. That should cause it to execute the new code.

```
'Create the new element.
Dim ScriptElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
ScriptElement.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
ScriptElement.InnerText = "hX_6.addBehavior(""f:button"", ""onclick"", new hX_6.JSFBehaviorGeneric(""action:confirm"",""target:Save or not?"")); hX_6.onPageLoad();"

'Add it to the page.
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(ScriptElement)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to invoke the apparent button itself, rather than the script that adds its event handler, you can try this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<button id here>").InvokeMember("click")
```

- where `<button id here>` is the ID of the button you want to press. Use Internet Explorer's or Chrome's Developer Tools to find this.

Comment: I ll try. Thank you.

Comment: But how can i invoke “confirm” button by using code?

Comment: @ismailakarim : Oh so you want to invoke _the button_ rather than re-running this code? Well then I need to know what that button's HTML code looks like.

Comment: A new windows appears and ask me “Save or not”. I think that is a java window. There is no HTML button about saving or not.

Comment: @ismailakarim : Well this appears to be attached to a button. `f:button` might be that button's ID. Try this: `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("f:button").InvokeMember("click")`.

Comment: I can show it via a video. I looked at the HTML codes. After invoke a button a java window appears and ask me again “Save or Not”. I can not find HTML codes of save button. Becouse i think the new window not HTML. Pure Java.

Comment: @ismailakarim : If there is a button on the page you can use the IE or Chrome developer tools and select it on order to find its HTML.

Comment: Ok i ll check this

Comment: @ismailakarim : Press F12 in either browser, then in the window/panel that opens press the little arrow in the top-left corner. Now select your button on the page and you should be shown its HTML code. -- Also, try my new code suggestion in your app.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No. I am trying now. But it seems not ok. Browser do not show me the new "Save Window"'s HTML codes.

Comment: @ismailakarim : Have you inspected the button using Chrome's DevTools? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Karekod Sonlandırma İptal" id="f:buttonKarekodIptal" name="f:buttonKarekodIptal" class="commandExButton" tabindex="91" onclick="return(hX_6.runEvent(this, event));">`

Comment: `Dim karekodac As HtmlElement = Me.Document.GetElementById("f:buttonKarekodIptal").InvokeMember("click")` that is my code. After fire the code new window appears

Comment: @ismailakarim : Ah so you found it! Great! You should write that as your own answer and accept it when time allows. **EDIT:** I don't think you should remove that code unless you added it yourself. You don't need my code any longer however.